# ssh-copy-id has no effect

Tags: ssh, openssh

I'm trying to transfer my public key to my server. I've ran ssh-copy-id to do so but nothing really happened. Nor the .ssh nor the authorized_keys folder is made. The public key is not in my home directory but I think is stored elsewhere since. What am I doing wrong?

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
john@mydomain's password:

Number of key(s) added: 1

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh 'john@mydomain'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.
```

Comment: What's the output of `ssh john@mydomain cat '~/.ssh/authorized_keys'`? Does your public key appear in it?

Answer (score 2):

When you generated your keys, that is usually the dir that they will be in if you didn't specify a full path. Try this?

start at your ~/

```sh
cd
mkdir .ssh
chmod 700 .ssh
cd .ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f id_rsa
ssh-copy-id <ip>
```

Comment: It sounds like the user didn't actually make any keys, he/she just tried to copy. Following these commands should help.

Comment: I generated my keys on my home computer. On my home computer I can find them. They are were they are supposed to be. It is the transfer of my public key from my home computer to my server that is unsuccessfull (although no errors are prompted). I resolved my problem by making the required folders myself on the server and touching the authorized_keys, then ssh-copy-id worked just fine